# Aurialis/Auriolis(?) Book about alien cats on planet with heavy storms

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in Dutch in the early or mid-nineties.

I believe the plot had to do with a human male landing on a planet where catlike aliens had to travel around the entire planet where heavy winds were blowing regularly. They use their tail with a hook on the end to move forward in heavy storms.

Two of the feline aliens have sex at one point by interlocking their tails.

The title was something like Aurialis/Auriolis.

Comment: *Ailouros* is the Greek word for "cat," so that was probably the basis on this book's title.

Answer (score 4):

[*Coriolis, de stormplaneet*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6729603-coriolis-de-stormplaneet), by Gerben Hellinga

> On the planet Coriolis, an incessant storm with wind force ten rages,
> the trade storm. Plants and animals have adapted to this condition.
> Coriolis is inhabited by the osborks, feline predators, who
> communicate through their thoughts. Kazazi Bogdan Siliqi is a female
> osbork; she is sentenced to a circumnavigation of the world as a
> Follower of the Trades. On the way she meets a human who has made an
> emergency landing on Coriolis. They befriend and together they try to
> survive amidst all the dangers that nature and the other Osborks have
> in store for them.

[image]